# Throttle displaying of div and children, using recursive function Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Originally I had a huge div with many child elements that was `display: none` and then I would simply set it to `display: ''` and the entire div would be visible. This created some noticable lag. I want to throttle it by displaying the elements one by one with a timeout but the function I created causes strange behavior. It actually works fine if you remove the `setTimeout` but without `setTimeout` there is still the same lag.

```
function throttleDisplay(page) {
    page.style.display = '';
    var children = page.children;
    if (!children.length) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = children[i];
        setTimeout(function() {
            throttleDisplay(child);
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put up a fiddle or something?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the content of the webpage is private

Comment: make some demo content or something, we want to help

Comment: Doesnt seem to happen in jsbin? not sure whats up http://jsbin.com/pikakihifo/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Several problems.

1. Revealing the top-level `<div>` all-at-once by setting `display:block` (or `display:''`) will trigger just one page re-flow and re-paint, and will therefore create less "lag" than recursively revealing children, which will thrash your layout with exponential re-flows and re-paints.
2. `setTimeout` (and therefore its callback) is called for each child in the `for` loop (at one recursion tier) more or less simultaneously, so this throttles the reveal of descendant elements, not sibling elements.
3. Unless every element in the tree begins with `display:none`, setting the top-level element to `display:''` will reveal the tree all-at-once, anyway.

Are you certain that revealing the top-level `<div>` is the cause of your lag? **A code sample might help the community find the source of your problem.** A first suggestion would be to wrap the code that changes `display` inside a `requestAnimationFrame`. ([MDN on rAF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame))

Note 1A: I say "exponential" because you are revealing each child separately versus one container element, but of course the number of operations is linear with respect to the total number of descendants, ignoring their relative "container"/"contained" status.

Note 1B: It is not necessarily the case that this code will "thrash" your layout; you are performing a sequence of "writes" to the layout which will probably be automatically batched at the end of a frame by a modern browser, provided all the function calls can be processed within the space of a frame (~17ms), and we are speaking only about the non-throttled sibling reveals. The asynchronous throttling would allow "reads" from other parts of your code, forcing a re-flow, but since the delay is already the length of 5 frames, this is irrelevant. The point is that this code will not reduce "lag" of any kind.

Comment: Yes all elements have display none. Im really confused on part 2.

Comment: Update: requestAnimationFrame helped a bit but still noticable

Comment: @DanielKobe You invoke `setTimeout` at each iteration of the `for` loop with a delay of 100ms. This is an asynchronous operation; the `for` loop continues without waiting for those 100ms to elapse. So the calls to `setTimeout` happen "simultaneously" for each child; then, after 100ms, the callback function (`throttleDisplay`) is called "simultaneously" for each child. Therefore, there is a 100ms delay between revealing *levels* in the DOM tree, but not between children of the same parent element ("siblings").

Comment: @DanielKobe Did you give all elements `display:none` specifically to work with this `throttleDisplay` function, or did they all have `display:none` when you first encountered the problem you're trying to solve? I may have misunderstood your question. For more constructive answers, be clearer about the difference between "lag" and "throttling" (both are forms of "delay") so we understand how your solution is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this-vidor for explaining some of the problems with the function I had. I don't know what exactly was causing the very strange behavior in my particular situation because I tried to reproduce it with fake data on jsbin and did not have the same problems. I deciding on building a custom function for my particular situation it looks like this

```
Messages: function (page) {
    var messageCount = 0;
    var curThrottle = 0;
    page.style.display = '';
    var children = page.children;
    var lastChild = children[children.length - 1];
    var lastChildsChildren = lastChild.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < lastChildsChildren.length; i++) {
        var child = lastChildsChildren[i];
        child.style.display = '';
        var messages = child.children[child.children.length - 1].children;
        for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
            if (++messageCount%40 === 0) curThrottle += 30;
            var message = messages[j];
            (function (message) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    message.style.display = '';
                }, curThrottle);
            })(message);
        }
    }
}
```